# how generating transparent GIF with golang using png images?

Tags: go, image-processing

I have a function that reads a lists of files and create a gif using each file on the list as a frame. But I have a problem. If my frames are png images with transparent background the output GIF have a black background.

I've read on the Internet that `image.Paletted` is related to the problem but I don't quite understand the issue.

```go
func createAnimation(files []string, directory, filename string) {
    outGif := &gif.GIF{}

    for _, name := range files {
        input := fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", directory, name)

        f, err := os.Open(input)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        imageData, _, err := image.Decode(f)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        buf := bytes.Buffer{}

        if err = gif.Encode(&buf, imageData, nil); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        inGif, err := gif.Decode(&buf)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        f.Close()

        outGif.Image = append(outGif.Image, inGif.(*image.Paletted))
        outGif.Delay = append(outGif.Delay, 0)
    }

    output := fmt.Sprintf("FINAL_%s.gif", filename)

    f, err := os.Create(output)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    gif.EncodeAll(f, outGif)

    err = os.Rename(output, fmt.Sprintf("%s/%s", directory, output))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

}
```

Files is a slice of filenames e.g. `{"base1.png", "base2.png"}` and so on.

What should I check or modify in order to generate a transparent gif?

Answer (score 0):

instead of encoding and decoding image you can use draw.Draw nethod. Just create a `image.Paleted` of size of the loaded image, specify palette you need (include transparent color) and perform draw call.

```
func Draw(dst Image, r image.Rectangle, src image.Image, sp image.Point, op Op)
// so
draw.Draw(newEmptyPalettedInage, loadedImage.Bounds(), loadedImage, loadedImage.Bounds().Min, 0)
```